# unconverted data remains on converting string to date

Tags: python

A simple code as below always gives me an error complaining about `unconverted data remains: 16`

```
print (date)
print (type(date))
print (len(date))
dt = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y")
```

The prints output 14/11/2016
, str and 10

What is wrong with this code and why does it complain about 16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), `%y` is "*Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.    00, 01, …, 99*". This conversion requires exactly two characters. Thus your conversion eats `20` but leaves `16` unconverted.

You want to use `%Y`, "*Year with century as a decimal number.  0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999*".

```
dt = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```